# With pointed fangs I sit and wait

Tags: riddle

> With pointed fangs I sit and wait;
>
> With piercing force I crunch out fate;
>
> Grabbing victims, proclaiming might;
>
> Physically joining with a single bite.

**What am I?**

Comment: Is this from a specific website or magazine? If so, could you please cite the sources, too?

Comment: The same riddle is found in many other places on the web (usually with "bloodless" before "victims"). None of the ones on the first page of the Google search results (at least for me, on this occasion) gives any indication of the original source. One of them, somewhere on whisper.sh, had the same wording as bobjoe has used here; perhaps that's where he copied it from. I don't think there's much prospect of identifying the original creator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!
I believe the answer is

> Stapler, as this useful tool does all of the above in the question.

EDIT:

I will explain the "crunch out fate part"

> *Pretend that you are in English, and your teacher says that you have to turn in your essay that is worth $10^9$ points. This will determine you grade, obviously. You take out your papers and you realize "OH NO! I HAVEN'T STAPLED THEM YET." So you go to the front of the desk. 10 seconds until the bell rings. You slam the stapler on your paper and by some pure force of evil, the stapler jams. You fail English.*

Comment: Good guess, this sounds right.

Comment: All fit, but 'crunch out fate' ?

Comment: @AmitNaidu save loose sheets from the fate of getting lost? But that's a stretch.

Answer (score 9):

I agree more with NL628, but to offer a different answer:

> Cupid and his arrows of love

Comment: Haha, good one! I don't think Cupid bites though xD +1

Comment: @MIcCrozier No, but an arrow or generally a weapon is often considered to have a "bite".

Comment: Haha Nice one +1

Answer (score 7):

I thought you might be a:

> Venus Fly Trap

(Sorry, that was what first came to mind - it meets the requirements, wouldn't you say?)

Comment: answers without explanations are often deleted

Comment: Most of the ones here don't have explanations, but I'll add one.

Comment: This is what I thought it was at first too

Answer (score 5):

It can be

> Paper pin or thumb/drawing pin as they are more openly pointed and fanged.

Because

> As the first line says : With pointed fangs I sit and wait; a paper pin or drawing pins are with pointed fangs and are kept in a box or storage. Second line says : With piercing force I crunch out fate; one has to push them with force and then they pierce through some paper or any other object. Third line says : Grabbing victims, proclaiming might; after they are pushed in they hold together the papers or sheets together. and lastly :Physically joining with a single bite; they physically join those paper with the board and hold them together with one single hole or bite.

Answer (score 3):

How about a:

> Vampire tap/clamp

[Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_tap)

> The fangs are the implements of connection which pierce the cable, in a physical join.  Crunching out fate is the data manipulation possible once the connection is established.

Yeah, victims and proclamations are a bit of a problem  :-{

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please give an explanation to your answer.